# Whats the best way of searching text files for specific text then reading the whole line? (visual basic)

Tags: vb.net, text-files

Btw I am quite new-ish to VB, idk if thats important or not

In a text file, I have the structure per line as: ID, username, password, points.
In this case I want to retrieve points, I had the user input the username and password.

I think the easiest method would be to use the username and/or password to search the file and retrieve the points, but I don't know how to actually code this.

Comment: [File.ReadLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) + [string.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split).

Comment: Hopefully you aren't storing passwords in plain text?! But yeah, do the ReadAllLines() which will return you an array of lines. You can then loop through each of those lines, and then do the Split() on a separator (is it tab, comma, or some other delimiter) which will give you an array of the column-specific data (i.e. password data) for that line.  From there, you should be good.

Comment: You have so many different options though. You could use the methods we listed above (reading all lines at once), or you could use a StreamReader (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) to read line by line.  But pick a route and start coding...come back if you have any errors and we can help you.

Comment: @JohnPete22  `File.ReadLines()` is not the same as `File.ReadAllLines()`. See the remarks section in the Docs. The former returns an enumerator which you can iterate, reading one line at the time. It doesn't load in memory the whole file as the latter.